# Codeigniter Ajax - Not Working Getting Network Error

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to CI.

I tried to make an ajax process. 
But i am getting the following error.

**NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - 
The action you have requested is not allowed**

Here is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#submit').click(function() {
            var form_data = {
            comment : $('#comment').val(),
            ajax : '1'
       };
       $.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>comment/insert",
          type: 'POST',
          async : false,
          data: form_data,
          success: function(msg) {
           $('#emsg').html(msg);
          }
       });
      return false;
   });
 });
 </script>
 But when i access the url directly 
 <?php echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>comment/insert
```

It's working correctly.

So please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks to all

Comment: that means something is breaking on the script executing on the other end of the ajax call.  perhaps verify your post data via console?

Comment: This is the post data
comment=sd&ajax=1
It's working correctly

Comment: when you access the url directly, you're not posting to it though.  i would say have your insert function var_dump the post data and then it will appear in the #emsg containter on the page.  then try to run the function by accessing directly using that data plugged in.

Comment: post comment controller code please?

Comment: in insert function i just wrote echo "test" that's it.

Comment: When i access the url directly i'm getting the output simply "Test".

Comment: I have doubt, this is may occurs because of some security reason?

Comment: how is the error presenting itself...

Comment: hey when i change the csrf protection to false then it works

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things here:

If you are going to use `base_url`, there is no need to assign it to, or access it from the config array. It is available to you as `base_url()`. As is `site_url()`. Check out CodeIgniter's documention on the [URL Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html).

Now, with that said, I recommend not using the `site_url()` or `base_url()` functions at all in your `href`'s, or `src`'s, except for *once*:

In the `<head>` of your HTML document use the `<base>` tag. If you write: `<base href="<?= site_url();?>">`, you can reference all of your controllers and functions using simply: `controller/function`. No need to keep calling `site_url()` or `base_url()`, because `<base>`specifies a base URL for all relative URLs contained in the document.

Next, If you're getting 500 Internal Server Errors, ensure that PHP error reporting is enabled. In the constructor of your controller call `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Now when errors occur, use Chrome Dev Tools to inspect the response from the server; fire the ajax request and head into the Network tab of dev tools. Find the Ajax POST, click it, and you'll be able to inspect what the server responded with.

Answer (score 0):

This problem causes due to the following reasons

1. syntex error
2. Duplicate function in controller or model